# Check if the related values in two columns are equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the following Excel sheet I want to find a formula in the third column to do the following:
For example, in the first column for all "A" Values if the related values on the second column are not equal, convert all to True and if they are equal keep it as it is (like for "B")

| First | Second | Third |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | True |  |
| A | Fasle |  |
| B | False |  |
| B | Fasle |  |
| B | False |  |
| B | Fasle |  |
| C | True |  |
| C | Fasle |  |
| C | True |  |

Comment: are the different "false"-values typos?

Comment: Please include your attempted formula *and* your version of Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Fasle are actually typos for FALSE, you could just check for existence of *any* true in column B with same letter in column A:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,TRUE)>0
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, Fasle are typos, also you solution is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use one of the following formulas:

Remark: I am using a table (insert > table)

self-explaining:

```vb
= LET(
filterByFirst,FILTER([Second],[First]=[@First]),
uniqueValues,UNIQUE(filterByFirst),
cntUniqueValues,ROWS(uniqueValues),
IF(cntUniqueValues=1,[@Second],"True")
)
```

condensed version:

```
=IF(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER([Second],[First]=[@First])))=1,[@Second],"True")
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what do I need, there are some function new for me.